# How to get the time of the TimePickerDialog in the EditText in another fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dialog, timepicker

I am trying to get the time of my `TimePickerDialog` to an `EditText` in the `FinishPostFragment`.

I am showing the selected time right now in a Toast but how can I show the data in the `EditText` in the `FinishPostFragment`?

FinishPostFragment in my onCreateView:

```
timeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // view TimePickerDialog
            showTimeDialog(v);
        }
    });
```

FinishPostFragment outside my onCreateView:

```
public void showTimeDialog(View v){
    TimeDialogFragment tdf = new TimeDialogFragment();
    tdf.show(getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "TimePickerFragment");
}

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener test = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        time_finish.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute));
    }
};
```

TimeSettings.java:

```
public class TimeSettings implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    Context context;

    public TimeSettings(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Selected time is hour: " +hourOfDay+ " minute: " + minute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

TimeDialogFragment:

```
public class TimeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog dialog;

        TimeSettings timeSettings = new TimeSettings(getActivity());
        dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), timeSettings, hour, minute,
                android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something close to what you have that might work is the following. Have your `FinishPostFragment` implement `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` itself instead.

Show the `TimeDialaogFragment` using `getChildFragmentManager()` instead.

```
tdf.show(getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "TimePickerFragment");
```

That will make it so you can then do the following in your `TimeDialogFragment.onCreateView` to send the selected time directly to the `FinishPostFragment`.

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener = 
        (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getParentFragment();

dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), timeSetListener, hour, minute,
        android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

Note in order to use `getParentFragment()` you must be using the support library or targeting API 17+.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

Toast.makeText(context, "Selected time is hour: " +hourOfDay+ " minute: " + minute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
String time = "   "+hourString+"h"+minuteString+"m"+secondString+"s";
    yourTextView.setText(time);

}
```

try this settting text to your textview like this.